# List comprehension syntax - how to use ... if... else?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm just getting started with Python and was reading about list comprehensions.

The following code:

```
my_list = [x ** x for x in range(1,11) if x % 2 == 0]
print(my_list)
```

... produces this output:

```
[4, 256, 46656, 16777216, 10000000000]
```

I then tried this code:

```
my_list = [x ** x for x in range(1,11) if x % 2 == 0 else 7]
print(my_list)
```

... but I got a syntax error starting at the second "e" in else.

Can someone explain why I'm getting a syntax error? I'd like to have the list create a list of even squares based on the value of the base (x), and to have the value "49" if the list value is not an "even number" square.

Comment: `[x ** x if x % 2 == 0 else 49 for x in range(1,11)]` .. looking for a dupe

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you would want

```
my_list = [x ** x if x % 2 == 0 else 49 for x in range(1,11)]
```

If you use an `if` at the end of a list comprehension like that, it is used to select *which* elements to include. If you want a different result depending on the case, you need to use a ternary `if` at the beginning instead.

For more info, take a look at the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). To quote:

> A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression followed by a for clause, then zero or more for or if clauses. The result will be a new list resulting from evaluating the expression in the context of the for and if clauses which follow it.

There is no support for `else` here, presumably because a ternary `if` (`if condition then foo else bar`) in the 'body' of the comprehension already accomplishes this and ["There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3)

Comment: Interesting. Is there a Python doc reference to this? I want to know more!

Comment: I put up an edit with a little more explanation